# Ruby on Rails: Navigation Between Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to create a button on the `show` page that will allow users to navigate between different comments.

And for some reason, I keep getting either `article :id` or `comment :id` could not be found.

Any idea why that happens?

```
#comment.rb

def self.next(comment, key = :id)
  self.where("#{key} > ?", comment.send(key)).first
end


#comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_article
  before_action :find_comment

  def next_comment 
    @next_comment = @scope.next(@comment)
  end

  def scope
    @scope = @article.comments
  end
end

#comments/show.html.haml
= link_to "Next Comment", comments_next_comment_path(@next_comment)
```

EDIT: The problem was in my routes, which has now been fixed. 
But now I get the following error:

```
undefined method "next" for nil:NilClass
```

EDIT 2:

Here's the log--and the URL goes to `http://localhost:3000/articles/14/comments/56/next_comment`

Now it doesn't raise any errors but simply displays a blank page instead of going to the next comment URL which is `http://localhost:3000/articles/14/comments/70`

```
 Parameters: {"article_id"=>"14", "id"=>"56"}
  Article Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 14]]
  Comment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 56]]
  Rendered comments/next_comments.html.haml within layouts/application (0.2ms)
```

Comment: Can you provide more information as to where the error is being raised? Is it in one of the `before_action` methods or somewhere else?

Comment: Could this be occurring because there is no next comment, i.e. you've clicked next from the last comment? Or is it happening throughout?

Comment: Please see edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@scope` instance variable is undefined (and therefore `nil`) prior to you using it. Just change it to the following and it should work

```
def next_comment
  @next_comment = scope.next(@comment)
end

def scope
  @scope ||= @article.comments
end
```